# How can I find or change my password and login for windows Azure?

Tags: azure, ssh, connection, azure-connect

It's really big problem for me - ugly UI, where I can't see ssh connection requisites for my new virtual machine instance. Is it possible to change password? Password and login from my manage.windowsazure.com panel is not approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you are talking about a Linux VM? When creating a new VM you have to supply a username and password or you can upload an SSH key. The standard username is `azureuser`. There is no way to reset the password of a VM w/o having access to it.

**Update**: By now it's possible to create a new User/Password or upload a new SSH key via the new Azure Portal.

1. Got to https://portal.azure.com
2. Select your virtual machine
3. Click on `Settings`
4. Select `Reset Password`

Comment: I think I found a way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

1. Generate new certificate using this article: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/linux-use-ssh-key/
2. In Azure management console, go to "CLOUD SERVICES" -> your service -> certificates
3. Upload you new generated certificate
4. Now you can login with `ssh -i ~/.ssh/[private_key] azureuser@[yourappname].cloudapp.net`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing it on the machine.
Login to the Virtual Machine via SSH with your current password. and run `chpwd`

Comment: It's not working for me. I can't log in with my account password.